# Not getting invitation notifications on Google Play Game Services in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am having a problem when sending out invitations to Google Plus friends. My Unity game supports 4 players in total. When I send out 3 invitations, more often than not only 2 people out of these 3 get the invitations. The order is not consistent so 1 device might get it on my first attempt but does not receive it the second time round.

- Using plugin version 0.9.10
- All device accounts are in each others circles
- I am registering to the invitation delegate on the authentication callback
- If I call 'PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.AcceptFromInbox()', then I get to the see the invite but then I don't get to see the invitation variant.

I've see a lot of questions about this but none of them were in Unity and most remain unsolved up till now. Has anyone got invitations working properly in or outside of Unity?

Answer (score 0):

The [Quiz Racer sample](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/tree/master/samples/QuizRacer) is a 4 person real time multi-player game.  The invitation delegate is called when there is an invitation to handle.  One the parameters to the delegate is the Invitation object, which has a property named Variant.

```
public void OnInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation, bool shouldAutoAccept) {
    Debug.Log("invitation with variant " + invitation.Variant + " received");
    }
```

There was a problem being called when the game is not running which as been addressed in the latest plugin version.  This allows the registration of the delegate before calling activate, so the delegate is callable during the sign-in flow.

Comment: Thanks @ClaytonWilkinson however that doesn't answer the question.

I've updated to plugin version 0.9.11 now and I register for invitation delegates like this:

'code PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new'
'code PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()'
'code    .WithInvitationDelegate(OnInvitationReceived)'
'code        .Build();'

When I send an invitation, some of the other recipients still do not get the notification message sometimes.  The invitation gets to the device - I can see it by accessing the inbox - The question is why don't we always get a callback on the invitation delegate?

Comment: Its happening with me as well. I can send an invitation from device A to B and it gets  a callback where as if I swap the process, it doesn't get any callback. Moreover, I see it in Inbox. Just a quick question, if I accept that invitation from inbox, how can I get the gameVariant out of it as it directly takes me to OnRoomConnected(bool) callback.